# Applying a function across 3 columns in a data frame only returns one column

Tags: r

I am trying to normalize all columns within a data frame using the function written below.  When I try to apply it to all columns using the for loop below, the output returns only one column when I would expect three.  The output is normalized correctly suggesting the function works and the for loop is the issue.

seq_along(df) returns the same output

```
### example df

df <- cbind(as.data.frame(c(2:12), c(3:13), c(4:14)))

### normalization function
rescale <- function(x) {    
  (x - min(x, na.rm = TRUE)) / (max(x, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x, na.rm = TRUE))    
}


### for loop that returns one column although properly normalized

for (i in 1:ncol(df)){      
  i <- df[[i]]  
  output <- as.data.frame(rescale(i))
}
```

Comment: There is a `scale` function already and it can be used directly `scale(df)` also `cbind(as.data.frame` could be changed to `data.frame(`

Comment: You keep reassigning over the same `output` variable. You replace the value in each loop, you don't add to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of as.data.frame is `as.data.frame(x, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE, ...)`. That means that in the call `as.data.frame(c(2:12), c(3:13), c(4:14))` `c(3:13)` is being assigned to the argument ***row.names*** and `c(4:14)` to the ***ellipse***. This means that your data.frame only has one column: `2:12`.

The correct version should be: `df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(2:12), c(3:13), c(4:14)))`. Of course you should use the function `scale` instead of writing it yourself